# Keep Class toggled after Page Refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently working with a sliding button in CSS, HTML, and JQuery. I have a basic understanding of JQuery but an quite knowledgeable in CSS & HTML. I have had a slight problem though, whenever you press the button it works fine, but upon page reload it reverts back to the before toggled state. How might I fix this issue, open to any solution preferably client side?
(Below is a snippet of my button and the code alongside it)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-menu-lang-cont').click(function() {
    $('.handle').toggleClass('slide');
    $('.toggle-menu-lang-cont').toggleClass('color-swap');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.toggle-menu-lang-cont {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5vw;
  right: 5vw;
  max-width: 3.5vw;
  width: 3.5vw;
  max-height: 1.5vw;
  height: 1.5vw;
  border-radius: 1vw;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.15vw;
  right: .25vw;
  background-color: #0282E4;
  width: 1.25vw;
  height: 1.25vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0vw .15vw .15vw rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2vw;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.color-swap {
  background-color: #0282E4;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Code Project</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="toggle-menu-lang-cont">
    <div class="toggle-btn"></div>
    <div class="handle"></div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but you should checkout `Window.localStorage`. Link here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Store the state of the toggle in a localStorage and when page loads, lookup the stored value. Based on the stored value you can set the toggle button state.

Comment: I will look into it @Snehal Shah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to leverage `LocalStorage` at the time the switch is engaged. You then store the current state of the switch into storage. When the page loads, you check for both the existence of the storage key and the storage value. If the value is true (the switch is active), make the appropriate adjustments so that the correct classes are in place. If the switch is not activated, do nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function toggleHandle() {
    $('.handle').toggleClass('slide');
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem('switch-state') && localStorage.getItem('switch-state') === "true") {
    $('.toggle-menu-lang-cont').addClass('color-swap');
    toggleHandle(); 
  }

  $('.toggle-menu-lang-cont').click(function() {
    let el = $('.toggle-menu-lang-cont');
    toggleHandle();
    el.toggleClass('color-swap');
    localStorage.setItem('switch-state', el.hasClass('color-swap'));
  });
});
```

### Working Example

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antibland/zmnphvtc/9/)

Comment: I could kiss you! It works flawlessly, I appreciate your help greatly.

Comment: @JordanDunton A kiss might be nice, but choosing my answer as the selected answer would be preferred. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to save state, you need to save it somewhere.  If this state only needs to be accessed client side and never server side, you should use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.  The two are very similar but if you want the state to stick around for a long time, use `localStorage`.

You access values with:

```
localStorage.getItem("colorSwapState");
```

If the `item` does not exist, this returns `null`.  Otherwise the value is always returned as a string.

You set values with:

```
localStorage.setItem("colorSwapState", "swap");
```

To delete:

```
localStorage.removeItem('colorSwapState')
```

I would update your JavaScript to something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("colorSwapState") == "swap")
  {
    $('.handle').addClass('slide');
    $('.toggle-menu-lang-cont').addClass('color-swap');
  }

  $('.toggle-menu-lang-cont').click(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("colorSwapState") == "swap") {
      localStorage.removeItem("colorSwapState");
    } 
    else {
      localStorage.setItem("colorSwapState", "swap");
    }

    $('.handle').toggleClass('slide');
    $('.toggle-menu-lang-cont').toggleClass('color-swap');
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey, love it, works for the most part, unfortunately the handle (small circle) does not keep its position change. Could you please include the code for that as well. Much appreciated!

Comment: You just need to put `$('.handle').toggleClass('slide');` in the conditional.  I updated my example.