# Change button color when clicked - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

If the process is successful, I want to change the "btn-success" class to "btn-warning". 
Or we can update the color code to "# ffc107".
How can I do that?

Button ;

```
<button type="submit" name="teklifver" value="Teklif Ver" class="btn btn-block btn-success" id="teklifpasif">Teklif Ver</button>
```

Php Code;

```
...

    $insert=$query->execute(array(

        "arac_id" =>$arac_id,
        "kullanici_adsoyad"=>$kullcek['kullanici_adsoyad'],
        "ihale_secenek" =>$ihale_secenek

        ));


        if($insert)
        {

          header("Location:index.php");
          ?>

          <script>

            // -------- Must be "btn-warning" ------------

          </script>

          <?php 
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "olmadı";
        }

}  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple solution for this is trying `removeClass` and `addClass`

https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/#removeClass-className

```
$('#teklifpasif').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-warning');
```

Or you can also try `toggleClass`

https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className

```
$('#teklifpasif').toggleClass('btn-success btn-warning');
```

**Update**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#teklifpasif').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-warning');
 });
```

**ERROR**

the problem in you have added `header("Location:index.php");` before `script` so your script won't execute until you remove `header("Location:index.php");`

**remove `header("Location:index.php");`**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. Could there be an error in <script> codes?

Comment: I was able to change the button color with the method you said great. When you refresh the page, the color is restored. How can I get it permanent?

Comment: check this question you will get some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55819969/keep-class-toggled-after-page-refresh

Answer (score 0):

Those are some options for you in JavaScript and JQuery.

---

## In JQuery

### Change color

`$("#teklifpasif").css("background-color", "#ffc107");`

### Change class

`$('#teklifpasif').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-warning');`

### Toggle class

`$('#teklifpasif').toggleClass('btn-success btn-warning');`

---

## In plain JavaScript

### Change color

`document.getElementById("teklifpasif").style.color = "#ffc107";`

### Change class

```js
document.getElementById("teklifpasif").classList.remove('btn-success');
document.getElementById("teklifpasif").classList.add('btn-warning');
```

---

They all work, I tried them a while ago.

Just choose one of those options ^^

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately these did not work in my codes.